# Error caused in mutate function (mask$eval_all_mutate())

Tags: r, mutate

Don't know if I'm getting the syntax wrong or not. I've already downloaded the `dplyr` package and `tidyverse` package.

The code below is what I wrote:

```
Watch_time_hour <- mutate(twitchdata,Watch_time_hours == Watchtime(Minutes)/60)
```

Below is the error message I get from typing in this code.

> Problem while computing `..1 = Watch_time_hours == Watchtime(Minutes)/60`.
> Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
> ! object 'Watch_time_hours' not found

Comment: Try with `Watch_time_hours = Watchtime(Minutes)/60` using just one equal sign.

Comment: @stefan I get a new error with this code. Error in mutate(): ! Problem while computing Watch_time_hours = Watchtime(Minutes)/60. Caused by error in Watchtime(): ! could not find function "Watchtime" Watchtime(minutes) is an existing column in the data frame twtichdata –

Comment: In R a **A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number.** As your variable name includes `()` you have to wrap it in backticks "`".

Comment: @stefan I found out how to use the mutate function by renaming "Watch time(Minutes)" to WatchTime.Minutes and it worked. Then I found out you can use mutate to create another column named Watch time(Hours), but I still cannot do the calculation with the name Watch time(Hours). It gives me an error saying "! non-numeric argument to binary operator" when I put it in the backtics. Code that gives error - twitchdata_update <- mutate(twitchdata_update,'Watch Time(Minutes)' = 'Watch Time(Hours)'*60). Should I just keep WatchTime.Minutes then rename the column after I'm finished using calculations?